terraform cdktf get with dev_overrides provider not working
I new with cdktf, and I am facing a few weird issue when I try to add an local provider using the command line cdktf provider add hashicorp.com/edu/hashicups I receive this error
[root@linux iac]# cdktf provider add hashicorp.com/edu/hashicups
[2024-07-06T12:50:33.026] [INFO] default - Checking whether pre-built provider exists for the following constraints:
  provider: hashicorp.com/edu/hashicups
  version : latest
  language: typescript
  cdktf   : 0.20.8

[2024-07-06T12:50:33.572] [INFO] default - Pre-built provider does not exist for the given constraints.
[2024-07-06T12:50:33.579] [INFO] default - Adding local provider hashicorp.com/edu/hashicups with version constraint undefined to cdktf.json
Local providers have been updated. Running cdktf get to update...
⠼ downloading and generating modules and providers...
[2024-07-06T12:50:37.045] [ERROR] default - ╷
│ Error: Invalid provider registry host
│
│ The host "hashicorp.com" given in provider source address
│ "hashicorp.com/edu/hashicups" does not offer a Terraform provider registry.
╵

╷
│ Error: Invalid provider registry host
│
│ The host "hashicorp.com" given in provider source address
│ "hashicorp.com/edu/hashicups" does not offer a Terraform provider registry.
Error: non-zero exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cdktf-cli/bundle/bin/cmds/handlers.js:96:51560)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:629:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:488:12)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:457:11)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:488:12)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:337:12) {
  stderr: '\x1B[31m╷\x1B[0m\x1B[0m\n' +
    '\x1B[31m│\x1B[0m \x1B[0m\x1B[1m\x1B[31mError: \x1B[0m\x1B[0m\x1B[1mInvalid provider registry host\x1B[0m\n' +
    '\x1B[31m│\x1B[0m \x1B[0m\n' +
    '\x1B[31m│\x1B[0m \x1B[0m\x1B[0mThe host "hashicorp.com" given in provider source address\n' +
    '\x1B[31m│\x1B[0m \x1B[0m"hashicorp.com/edu/hashicups" does not offer a Terraform provider registry.\n' +
    '\x1B[31m╵\x1B[0m\x1B[0m\n'
}
⠴ downloading and generating modules and providers...
Error: non-zero exit code 1

The provider executable is here /root/go/bin and I already added inside the .terraformrc the following configurations:
provider_installation {
  dev_overrides {
    "hashicorp.com/edu/hashicups" = "/root/go/bin/"
  }
  direct {
  }
}

I tried with --force and --force-local parameter but without success. An I don't get the ./.gen/ classes that, as far as I could undesrtand, mandatory to import local providers inside my cdkft code.
I am using:

Terraform v1.9.1 on linux_amd64
cdktf 0.20.8
provider source code https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-hashicups folder 12-final

The weird part is if I try with HCL terraform script, terraform plan is working properly.
Anyone have any idea?
Thanks ;)

Can you add the cdktf.json file to the question?
